# Multiple Http calls not happening asynchronously in Angular2 in an Ionic2 Apllication

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, rxjs, observable

I am trying to call two web service call when the user will enter a page.
The first service call - webServiceCallFirst normally takes 50 seconds to execute and second service call - webServiceCallSecond takes 5 seconds to execute.

I am calling both the service when the view goes to ionViewDidLoad.

But the issue is that until the webServiceCallFirst is not returning result, the webServiceCallSecond is not getting called.
As per my understanding these two calls should happen asynchronously and webServiceCallSecond should return result first and then webServiceCallFirst.

What am i doing wrong?
Any help will be much appreciated.

This is how i am doing web service call-

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.remedyService.commonServiceCall('webServiceCallFirst',params).subscribe(
    data =>{
      console.log("webServiceCallFirst Success="+JSON.stringify(data));
      },
    err =>{
      console.log("webServiceCallFirst Error="+JSON.stringify(data));},
      },
     () =>{
            console.log("webServiceCallFirst Completed");
    });
    this.remedyService.commonServiceCall('webServiceCallSecond',params).subscribe(
      data =>{
        console.log("webServiceCallSecond Success="+JSON.stringify(data));
        },
      err =>{
        console.log("webServiceCallSecond Error="+JSON.stringify(data));},
        },
       () =>{
              console.log("webServiceCallSecond Completed");
      });
  }
```

My commonServiceCall method-

```
commonServiceCall(url,objForRequest)
{
  var url= "/"+url;
  var headers = new Headers();
  this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
  return Observable.fromPromise(
    this.appStorage.getValue('remedyAccessToken').then((value)=>{
      var token  = value.toString();
      console.log("TOKEN IN REMEDYSERVICES="+token);
      headers.append('Authorization', token);
      console.log("header value="+JSON.stringify(headers));
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      this.response = this.http.post(url,this.urlEncode(objForRequest),options).map(res => res.json());
      console.log("Response JSON="+JSON.stringify(this.response));
      return this.response.toPromise();
    })
  );
}
```

I am converting http post observable into a promise since i need to get a remedytoken from storage and the i am again converting the promise to observable and then subscribing in ionViewDidLoad.

P.S - I dont want to any rxJS merge to do both service call together.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert only the `this.appStorage.getToken` to observable.

```
commonServiceCall(url,objForRequest)
{
  var url= "/"+url;
  var headers = new Headers();
  this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
  return 
    Observable.fromPromise(this.appStorage.getValue('remedyAccessToken'))
.switchMap((value)=>{//use switchmap to call http observable.
      var token  = value.toString();
      console.log("TOKEN IN REMEDYSERVICES="+token);
      headers.append('Authorization', token);
      console.log("header value="+JSON.stringify(headers));
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      this.response = this.http.post(url,this.urlEncode(objForRequest),options).map(res => res.json());
      console.log("Response JSON="+JSON.stringify(this.response));
      return this.response;
    });
}
```

This should be simpler than converting promise to observable and then observable to promise.